# Finding convergence of the next function: $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n}x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

How can i find whether the next function converges: $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n}x^n$?

I thought about this question for quite a while, What's the trick?

Comment: The Ratio Test, if that's a "trick". Also, check the points $x=1$ and $x=-1$ separately.

Comment: Isn't the ratio test returns 1? (And then it's irrelevant?)

Comment: The ratio test returns $|x|$ for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: The Ratio Test, applied to $a_n={(\ln n)^3\over n}|x|^n$ returns $1\cdot |x|$. The series converges if this quantity is less than $1$ and diverges if this quantity is greater than $1$.

Comment: Oh, Right! forgot about that $|x|$ Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The only delicate point is: it diverges at $1$ by comparison with the harmonic series, but it converges at $-1$ by Leibniz as $(\ln n)^3/n$ is eventually decreasing and tends to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio test here will work nicely:

Recall that we apply the ratio test to the the *entire* summand:

$$a_n=\left({(\ln n)^3\over n}|x|^n\right)$$

and doing so here will give you the result $\;1\cdot |x|.\;$ So the series ***will converge*** $\forall x: |x| \lt 1$, and will diverge $\forall x:|x| > 1$.

What happens at $x = +1, x = -1\,$ remains to be determined, so be sure to test for convergence/divergence at $\;x = 1,\;$ and also at $\; x = -1.\;$

Comment: ..."will converge for $|x|<1$" and diverge for $|x|>1$. Why would we drop half of the conclusions?

Comment: Thanks, @julien (what goes unsaid, goes unsaid...so best to "say"!)

Comment: @amWhy: gets another thumbs-up from me +1